# Any way to run all hooks in pacman?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

Is there any way to tell pacman (Arch Linux) to just run all post-transaction hooks, as if it had just done a full system upgrade, but without installing any packages?

I just tried to do a full upgrade and my system crashed just as the hooks were being run at the end. I would like to run them all again in case anything got screwed up, but without having to go through re-installing all of the packages again. If not, is there any way I can tell it to run a list of hooks that I specify?